# Sequelize ARRAY type in model with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I need to pass an array in my Transactions model.
I did that :

```
// ... define function and other datas

method: {
      type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING(100)),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: TransactionsMethod,
        key: "id",
      },
    },
```

But it seems to work only with postgresql, what can I do to make the same thing for mySql ?

To be more clear, I have a transactionsMethod table with three different methods in.
I need to be able to access them here in my Transactions model.

Comment: What exact data type do you have in DB for this column?

Comment: @Anatoly The table is not created yet in the database. I would like to do that by .sync() the model but I get an error regarding the syntax of the ARRAY part

Comment: Can an array be used as a foreign key data type?

Comment: Do you plan to use something like UUIDs?

Comment: Not sure to understand (I am a beginner with Sequelize), so I will give an exemple to clarify what I need to do.

It is the same thing when you have user in your app, who can have roles (admin, contributor, moderator ...).

So, normally, you have a user table and a role table. And, in your user model, you have a "role" property which references to the role table.

Comment: Ok, what data type will you use for primary keys and foreign keys as well? Integer autoincremented or UUID (https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/)?

Comment: That selection will lead you to what exact type you can use in Sequelize

Comment: I think i have found a solution, just by using INTEGER instead of array with the id key, thanks for your help